# All mocha tests pass locally but fail on Travis CI

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, travis-ci

I am building an api, everything works locally but on Travis-CI, the test fails. For the first time I was getting "mocha: permission denied". I deleted node_modules  in my repository so that the Travis can install all dependacies with "npm install". And then I start getting this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqBm0.png)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in picture that you have supplied on remote machine `node --version` is `v0.10.48`. In that version Node.js is not supporting ES6 syntax.

In your `.travis.yml` file you need to set `node_js` version on which you want to run tests like this:

```
node_js:
  - 10
  - 9
  - 8
```

With this part your tests will be run on three version of Node.js. More information what you can put in `.travis.yml` you can find in [official documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/javascript-with-nodejs/).